# Cannot pass object, putExtra(), cannot be cast to android.os.Serializable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on my Android project. Delivery.java is the list of delivery, and I want to click on a selected delivery and redirect to DeliveryDetails.java, showing the details of the delivery.

But I got this:

> error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

And my app stopped/crash when I redirected to DeliveryDetails.java.

Here is my code:

**Delivery.java (sending data to DeliveryDetails.java)**

```
private ArrayList<Delivery> deliveryList;
private ListView lvDelivery;

lvDelivery.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Delivery selectedDelivery = deliveryList.get(i);
            Intent in = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("delivery", (Serializable) selectedDelivery);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

**DeliveryDetails.java (Read/Recieve the data from Delivery.java )**

```
Delivery delivery = (Delivery) getIntent.getSerializableExtra("product");
```

**Error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myproject.delivery, PID: 22095
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myproject.delivery.Delivery cannot be cast to android.os.Serializable
```

Comment: Does `Delivery` implemente `Serializable`interface?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the **Delivery** class **Serializable**, so you can pass your object from one Activity to another Activity.

But I will suggest you rather than using **Serializable**, use the **Parcelable** interface. Here is the example, how to make a class parcelabe and pass objects from one activity to another [click here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/)...

Here is **difference** between **Parcelabe** and **Serializable** [Difference](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development).